# React-Redux Search/Filter component countries API

Tags: reactjs, search, redux, filter, react-redux

I have problem with initialization of search and filter for ma countries api. I have stuck with problem how to implement code. I will be gratefull for any help or some advices how to do this. My files look like this:

**Store.js**

```
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore, compose } from 'redux'
import getCountries from './getCountries'

const initialState = {
        variable: {
            data: [],
    },
    filters: {
        searchPhrase: '',
        continent: ''
    }

}


const reducers = {
    variable: getCountries, // variablesReducer
}

const storeReducer = combineReducers(reducers)

const store = createStore(
    storeReducer,
    initialState,
    compose(applyMiddleware(), window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()) // przed deployem usunac
)
export default store
```

SearchPhraseRedux.js

```
//SearchEngine
export const getData = ({variable}, filters) => {
    if(!filters.searchPhrase){
        return variable.data
    }   
    //Logic


    
    //export const getCountryByName = ({variable}, name) => 
    //variable.data.find(e=>e.name.common === name)
}


const reducerName = 'variable'
const createActionName = (name) => `app/${reducerName}/${name}`

export const SET_DATA = createActionName("SET_DATA")
export const setData = payload => ({payload, type: SET_DATA})


export default function reducer(statePart=[], action={}){
    switch(action.type) {
        case SET_DATA:
            return {...statePart, data: action.payload}
            default:
                return statePart
    }
}
```

countryContainer.js

```
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { getData, setData} from '../../redux/getCountries'
import Countries from "./countries"


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    data: getData(state),
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>({
    setData: (value) => dispatch(setData(value)),
})


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Countries)
```

countries.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect} from 'react'
import Axios from 'axios'
import '../../../src/index.css'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'


const Countries = ({data,setData}) => {

    const url = 'https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all'

    useEffect(() => {
      Axios.get(url)
      .then((rest) =>{
        setData(rest.data)
      })
    },[url, setData])

  return (
    <div>
        <section className='grid'>    
            {data.map((country) => {
                const {population, region, capital} = country
                    const {png} = country.flags
                        const {official, common} = country.name
                    return <article key={common}>
                        <div> 
                              <Link classsName='link' to={`/countries/${common}`}>
                              <img src ={png} alt={official}/> 
                              </Link>  
                            <div className='details'>
                              <h3>{common}</h3>
                              <h4>Population: <span>{population}</span></h4>
                              <h4>Region: <span>{region}</span></h4>
                              <h4>Capital: <span>{capital}</span></h4> 
                              </div>                                        
                        </div>
                            </article>
                        })}
        </section>   
    </div>
  )
}

export default Countries
```

I have tried to get One country like this:

```
export const getCountryByName = ({variable}, name) => variable.data.find(e=>e.name.common === name)
```

but,by extending this code, it is difficult for me to make search and filter